# Advent of Code 2019 Day 3, Part 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

[Advent of Code, Day 3 Problem Definitions](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/3)

```
input1 = 'R995,U982,R941,U681,L40,D390,R223,U84,L549,U568,R693,D410,R779,U33,L54,D18,L201,U616,R583,D502,R307,U46,L726,D355,L62,D973,R134,U619,L952,U669,L28,U729,L622,D821,R814,D149,L713,U380,R720,U438,L112,U587,R161,U789,R959,U254,R51,U648,R259,U555,R863,U610,L33,D97,L825,D489,R836,D626,L849,D262,L380,U831,R650,U832,R339,D538,L49,D808,L873,D33,L405,D655,R884,D630,R589,D291,L675,D210,L211,D325,L934,D515,R896,U97,L639,U654,L301,U507,L642,D416,L325,U696,L3,U999,R88,D376,L187,U107,R394,U273,R117,D872,R162,D496,L599,D855,L961,U830,L156,U999,L896,D380,L476,U100,R848,U547,L266,D490,L87,D376,L428,U265,R645,U584,L623,D658,L103,U946,R162,U678,R532,D761,L141,D48,L487,D246,L85,D680,R859,D345,L499,D194,L815,D742,R700,D141,L482,D442,L943,D110,L892,D486,L581,U733,L109,D807,L474,U866,R537,U217,R237,U915,R523,D394,L509,U333,R734,U511,R482,D921,R658,U860,R112,U527,L175,D619,R140,D402,L254,D956,L556,U447,L518,U60,L306,U88,R311,U654,L551,D38,R750,U835,L784,U648,L374,U211,L635,U429,R129,U849,R411,D135,L980,U40,R480,D91,R881,D292,R474,D956,L89,D640,L997,D397,L145,D126,R936,U135,L167,U289,R560,D745,L699,U978,L459,D947,L782,U427,L784,D561,R985,D395,L358,D928,R697,U561,L432,U790,R112,D474,R852,U862,R721,D337,L355,U598,L94,D951,L903,D175,R981,D444,L690,D729,L537,D458,R883,U152,R125,D363,L90,U260,R410,D858,L825,U185,R502,D648,R793,D600,L589,U931,L772,D498,L871,U326,L587,D789,L934,D889,R621,U689,R454,U475,L166,U85,R749,D253,R234,D96,R367,D33,R831,D783,R577,U402,R482,D741,R737,D474,L666'
input2 = 'L996,D167,R633,D49,L319,D985,L504,U273,L330,U904,R741,U886,L719,D73,L570,U982,R121,U878,R36,U1,R459,D368,R229,D219,R191,U731,R493,U529,R53,D613,R690,U856,L470,D722,R464,D378,L187,U540,R990,U942,R574,D991,R29,D973,R905,D63,R745,D444,L546,U939,L848,U860,R877,D181,L392,D798,R564,D189,R14,U120,R118,D350,R798,U462,R335,D497,R916,D722,R398,U91,L284,U660,R759,U676,L270,U69,L774,D850,R440,D669,L994,U187,R698,U864,R362,U523,L128,U89,R272,D40,L134,U571,L594,D737,L830,D956,L213,D97,R833,U454,R319,U809,L506,D792,R746,U283,R858,D743,R107,U499,R102,D71,R822,U9,L547,D915,L717,D783,L53,U871,R920,U284,R378,U312,R970,D316,R243,D512,R439,U530,R246,D824,R294,D726,R541,D250,R859,D134,R893,U631,L288,D151,L796,D759,R17,D656,L562,U136,R861,U42,L66,U552,R240,D121,L966,U288,L810,D104,R332,U667,L63,D463,R527,D27,R238,D401,L397,D888,R168,U808,L976,D462,R299,U385,L183,U303,L121,U385,R260,U80,R420,D532,R725,U500,L376,U852,R98,D597,L10,D441,L510,D592,L652,D230,L290,U41,R521,U726,R444,U440,L192,D255,R690,U141,R21,U942,L31,U894,L994,U472,L460,D357,R150,D721,R125,D929,R473,U707,R670,D118,R255,U287,R290,D374,R223,U489,R533,U49,L833,D805,L549,D291,R288,D664,R639,U866,R205,D746,L832,U864,L774,U610,R186,D56,R517,U294,L935,D304,L581,U899,R749,U741,R569,U282,R460,D925,L431,D168,R506,D949,L39,D472,R379,D125,R243,U335,L310,D762,R412,U426,L584,D981,L971,U575,L129,U885,L946,D221,L779,U902,R251,U75,L729,D956,L211,D130,R7,U664,L915,D928,L613,U740,R572,U733,R277,U7,R953,D962,L635,U641,L199'

# Toggle part1/part2 (we'll pretend this is a good approach...)
part_one = False

def move_steps(points, move, x, y, direction, steps):
    for _ in range(move):
        x += direction[0]
        y += direction[1]
        steps +=1
        # Store the number of steps to this point only if we haven't 
        # been here - we want the smallest number of steps stored
        # for comparison purposes
        if not (x,y) in points:
            points[(x,y)] = steps
    return x, y, steps

def get_points(raw_points):
    # Build list of all points the command traverses
    input_points = raw_points.split(',')
    points = {}
    x = 0
    y = 0
    steps = 0
    for p in input_points:
        move = int(p[1:])
        if p[0] == 'R':
            x, y, steps = move_steps(points, move, x, y, (1,0), steps)
        if p[0] == 'L':
            x, y, steps = move_steps(points, move, x, y, (-1,0), steps)
        if p[0] == 'U':
            x, y, steps = move_steps(points, move, x, y, (0,1), steps)
        if p[0] == 'D':
            x, y, steps = move_steps(points, move, x, y, (0,-1), steps)
    return points

points_one = get_points(input1)
points_two = get_points(input2)

shortest_length = 9999999999999
# Check which points match and keep track of the shortest length between them
points = points_one.keys()
for p in points:
    if p in points_two.keys():
        if part_one:
            length = abs(p[0]) + abs(p[1])
        else:
            length = points_one[p] + points_two[p]
        if length < shortest_length:
            shortest_length = length 
print(shortest_length)
```

I'm not a huge fan of how this turned out.

I have a few ideas for ways to make it better but I am curious what sticks out first.

Comment: In the future could you tag all Python questions with the [tag:python] tag as well as the sub-version. This allows better visibility to your question as some people only watch the [tag:python] tag. Further more, since links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993) Thank you.

Comment: The current question title isn't useful without the external resource. Please [edit] to summarize the requirement in your own words. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight Your comment is confusing. Do you think there's a problem with the title or not?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, of course there's a problem with the title.  It's absolutely meaningless to anyone not familiar with the Advent of Code resource.

Comment: @TobySpeight The status quo of the site is that [titles](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Project+Euler) [like](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Hackerrank) [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Advent+of+code) are fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "Part 3"? Advent of Code problems are divided into two parts, not three. Do you have posted previous questions that are related?

Comment: Please add some description of the problem to the question itself, so that we're not dependent on the third party site to know *what the question is about*. (This makes the question put on-hold, not the title)

Answer (score 2):

#### *Towards better manageability and flexibility*

- **`get_points`** function

  Name of side `p[0]` and move range `int(p[1:])` are better unpacked and named once:

  ```
  side_name, move_range = p[0], int(p[1:])
  ```

  All those `if` conditions should be mutually exclusive `if .. elif .. elif ...`.
  But instead, a better and more flexible way would be to declare *"directions"* map at once:

  ```
  DIRECTIONS_MAP = {'R': (1, 0), 'L': (-1, 0), 'U': (0, 1), 'D': (0, -1)}
  ```

  then, there would only one condition for containment check.

  The final optimized function:

  ```
  def get_points(raw_points):
      # Build list of all points the command traverses
      input_points = raw_points.split(',')
      points = {}
      x = y = steps = 0
      for p in input_points:
          side_name, move_range = p[0], int(p[1:])
          if side_name in DIRECTIONS_MAP:
              x, y, steps = move_steps(points, move_range, x, y, DIRECTIONS_MAP[side_name], steps)

      return points
  ```
- *finding shortest distance between points*

  Instead of constant check for matched points with:

  ```
  points = points_one.keys()
  for p in points:
      if p in points_two.keys():
          ...
  ```

  a more flexible way is to get *intersection* between dictionaries key views at once:

  ```
  for p in points_one.keys() & points_two.keys():
  ```

  The whole block of statements is extracted into separate function **`find_shortest_distance`** with explicit responsibility and default arguments:

  ```
  def find_shortest_distance(input1, input2, shortest_length=9999999999999, part_one=False):
      points_one = get_points(input1)
      points_two = get_points(input2)

      # Check which points match and keep track of the shortest length between them
      for p in points_one.keys() & points_two.keys():
          if part_one:
              length = abs(p[0]) + abs(p[1])
          else:
              length = points_one[p] + points_two[p]
          if length < shortest_length:
              shortest_length = length
      return shortest_length
  ```

---

Sample usage:

```
input1 = 'R995,U982,R941,U681,L40,D390,R223,U84,L549,U568,R693,D410,R779,U33,L54,D18,L201,U616,R583,D502,R307,U46,L726,D355,L62,D973,R134,U619,L952,U669,L28,U729,L622,D821,R814,D149,L713,U380,R720,U438,L112,U587,R161,U789,R959,U254,R51,U648,R259,U555,R863,U610,L33,D97,L825,D489,R836,D626,L849,D262,L380,U831,R650,U832,R339,D538,L49,D808,L873,D33,L405,D655,R884,D630,R589,D291,L675,D210,L211,D325,L934,D515,R896,U97,L639,U654,L301,U507,L642,D416,L325,U696,L3,U999,R88,D376,L187,U107,R394,U273,R117,D872,R162,D496,L599,D855,L961,U830,L156,U999,L896,D380,L476,U100,R848,U547,L266,D490,L87,D376,L428,U265,R645,U584,L623,D658,L103,U946,R162,U678,R532,D761,L141,D48,L487,D246,L85,D680,R859,D345,L499,D194,L815,D742,R700,D141,L482,D442,L943,D110,L892,D486,L581,U733,L109,D807,L474,U866,R537,U217,R237,U915,R523,D394,L509,U333,R734,U511,R482,D921,R658,U860,R112,U527,L175,D619,R140,D402,L254,D956,L556,U447,L518,U60,L306,U88,R311,U654,L551,D38,R750,U835,L784,U648,L374,U211,L635,U429,R129,U849,R411,D135,L980,U40,R480,D91,R881,D292,R474,D956,L89,D640,L997,D397,L145,D126,R936,U135,L167,U289,R560,D745,L699,U978,L459,D947,L782,U427,L784,D561,R985,D395,L358,D928,R697,U561,L432,U790,R112,D474,R852,U862,R721,D337,L355,U598,L94,D951,L903,D175,R981,D444,L690,D729,L537,D458,R883,U152,R125,D363,L90,U260,R410,D858,L825,U185,R502,D648,R793,D600,L589,U931,L772,D498,L871,U326,L587,D789,L934,D889,R621,U689,R454,U475,L166,U85,R749,D253,R234,D96,R367,D33,R831,D783,R577,U402,R482,D741,R737,D474,L666'
input2 = 'L996,D167,R633,D49,L319,D985,L504,U273,L330,U904,R741,U886,L719,D73,L570,U982,R121,U878,R36,U1,R459,D368,R229,D219,R191,U731,R493,U529,R53,D613,R690,U856,L470,D722,R464,D378,L187,U540,R990,U942,R574,D991,R29,D973,R905,D63,R745,D444,L546,U939,L848,U860,R877,D181,L392,D798,R564,D189,R14,U120,R118,D350,R798,U462,R335,D497,R916,D722,R398,U91,L284,U660,R759,U676,L270,U69,L774,D850,R440,D669,L994,U187,R698,U864,R362,U523,L128,U89,R272,D40,L134,U571,L594,D737,L830,D956,L213,D97,R833,U454,R319,U809,L506,D792,R746,U283,R858,D743,R107,U499,R102,D71,R822,U9,L547,D915,L717,D783,L53,U871,R920,U284,R378,U312,R970,D316,R243,D512,R439,U530,R246,D824,R294,D726,R541,D250,R859,D134,R893,U631,L288,D151,L796,D759,R17,D656,L562,U136,R861,U42,L66,U552,R240,D121,L966,U288,L810,D104,R332,U667,L63,D463,R527,D27,R238,D401,L397,D888,R168,U808,L976,D462,R299,U385,L183,U303,L121,U385,R260,U80,R420,D532,R725,U500,L376,U852,R98,D597,L10,D441,L510,D592,L652,D230,L290,U41,R521,U726,R444,U440,L192,D255,R690,U141,R21,U942,L31,U894,L994,U472,L460,D357,R150,D721,R125,D929,R473,U707,R670,D118,R255,U287,R290,D374,R223,U489,R533,U49,L833,D805,L549,D291,R288,D664,R639,U866,R205,D746,L832,U864,L774,U610,R186,D56,R517,U294,L935,D304,L581,U899,R749,U741,R569,U282,R460,D925,L431,D168,R506,D949,L39,D472,R379,D125,R243,U335,L310,D762,R412,U426,L584,D981,L971,U575,L129,U885,L946,D221,L779,U902,R251,U75,L729,D956,L211,D130,R7,U664,L915,D928,L613,U740,R572,U733,R277,U7,R953,D962,L635,U641,L199'

print(find_shortest_distance(input1, input2))   # 32132
```